# Why can't autoconf find `libtcmalloc`?

Tags: libraries, autoconf

I'm trying to compile a complex numerical simulation software. After running `autoconf` and then `./configure ...` (with some other flags), I see the following in the output:

```
checking for malloc in -ltcmalloc... no
configure: WARNING: No tcmalloc support available.
```

After looking in `configure.in` I found:

```bsh
%zsh> grep 'tcmalloc' configure.in
    AC_CHECK_LIB(tcmalloc,malloc,,AC_MSG_WARN([No tcmalloc support available.]))
```

I have [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) installed which should provide tcmalloc I think. I do have a few libraries that are called something like that:

```bsh
%zsh> ldconfig -p|grep 'tcmalloc'
    libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4
    libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so
    libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
    libtcmalloc_minimal.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so
    libtcmalloc_debug.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_debug.so.4
    libtcmalloc_debug.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_debug.so
    libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4
    libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so
    libtcmalloc.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4
    libtcmalloc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so
```

I tried adding `libtcmalloc` to the list in `configure.in` but I just get:

```
checking for tcmalloc in -llibtcmalloc... ./configure: line 11516: WARNING:: command not found
no
```

Is there a way to get autoconf's `AC_CHECK_LIB` to detect my tcmalloc library?

Comment: What does your `config.log` file say around the failing test?  There are two things that are strange here: 1) You get a "command not found" error, and 2) it's testing with `-llibtcmalloc` instead of `-ltcmalloc`.  If you can look in the `config.log` file for why this is so, then maybe we could sort this out.  If you could mention what the software is called and where to find it, we could test compiling it for ourselves to see whether we too get the same error.

Comment: Let us also know if you modified the `configure`, `configure.in` or similar file in the source distribution.

Comment: @they Thanks, I seem to have messed something up last time. I modified `configure.in` at some point, as mentioned, hence the `-llibtcmalloc` part. Surprisingly, in a fresh source tree, I can't reproduce the warning anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a "fix" or a "workaround", and I realise it's hard to help without more information about the software in question, but I was able to avoid the warning by explicitly adding `-ltcmalloc` to LIBS in the configure flag:

```
./configure LIBS='-ltcmalloc ...' ...
```

---

Update 27 Nov:

**I somehow can't reproduce the warning anymore, even without the workaround. It's possible that I used a slightly different set of configure fags, or had somehow messed up my configure scripts.** I'll leave this here in case the workaround is helpful to others.

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution.